# Trying to force different sized blocks float:left and stick to the top..

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to style a page containing a lot of float-left-divs with different sizes.
i have 3 divs in a line, they all have the same width but the height depends on the contents of each div.
the problem looks like this:
I want the top of div-5 to stick to the bottom of div-2, the same widh div-6 and div-3
and so on..
I just want them all to stick to the top, as much as it's possible.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanx!

Comment: A simple diagram would help us visualize what you want.

Comment: paste your code on to a http://jsfiddle.net and share the link here

Comment: But include the code here to, not just on http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just try the using the margin-top tag. Example:

```
div { margin-top: -500; }
```

It would go up and then you just have to fit it in.
Or you can also use:

```
position: absolute;
```

and then just use margin to fit it as you want